# Integral of a conditional uniform distribution leads to improper integral

Tags: uniform-distribution, integral

I have two uniforms distributions, $X_1 \sim\it{U}(a,b)$ and $X_2\sim\it{U}(X_1+\delta,b+\delta)$. I would like to compute $P(X_2\in[a+\delta,b+\delta])$. So I do this:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X_2\in[a+\delta,b+\delta]) & = & \int_{a}^{b} P(X_2\in[a+\delta,b+\delta]|X_1=y)\cdot P(X_1=y) dy\\
 & = & \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{b-y} dy\\
 & = & \frac{1}{b-a} \ln\Bigg(\frac{b-a}{b-b}\Bigg)
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The wrong result is related to the fact that a uniform distribution has probability $\frac{1}{x}$, but it doesn't work for $x<1$ (in this case, the fraction becomes bigger than 1...).

How do we solve this problem formally, in a clean way?

Comment: Strictly speaking, $P(X_2 = x) = 0$ for every $x$, since $X_2$ is continuous. You can compute the density of $X_2$, which can be greater than one since it is not a probability.

Comment: @JonathanChristensen: Is it more correct like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see that the answer is $1$ without any calculation. By definition, you have $a \le X_1 \le b$ and $X_1+\delta \le X_2 \le b+\delta$, so:
$$\begin{align}
X_2 &\ge X_1 + \delta \ge a + \delta \quad \text{ and }\\
X_2 &\le b + \delta
\end{align}$$
So $\Pr(X_2 \in [a+\delta, b+\delta]) = 1$.

---

A uniform distribution over an interval of length $l > 0$ has [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) $1/l$ at every point. When you integrate this $1/l$ over the interval you get $1$ as you should; whether $l < 1$ or $l > 1$ is irrelevant. Also, the actual probability of taking any particular exact value is $0$, not $1/l$ as you seem to think. (Your $P(X_1=y)$ is $0$ for any $y$.) For continuous variables, we need to work with the [probability density function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), not the [probability mass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function).

So with all that in mind, the correct calculation would be as follows. The density $f_1(x)$ of $X_1$ is $\frac{1}{b-a}$ for $x \in (a,b)$, and $0$ outside. The density $f_2(x)$ of $X_2$, for a given value of $X_1$ (so let's write it as $f_{2,X_1}(x)$ actually), is $\frac{1}{b-X_1}$ for $x \in (X_1+\delta, b+\delta)$, and $0$ outside. To get this density function as a value of $x$ alone, without depending on the value of $X_1$, you need to integrate over all values $y$ of $X_1$: that is, $$f_2(x) = \int_{y} f_{2,y}(x)f_1(y) dy.$$

Now note that for the second factor $f_1(y)$ to be nonzero, you need $a \le y \le b$ as we said above. For the first factor $f_{2,y}(x)$ to be nonzero, you need $y+\delta \le x \le b+\delta$, so you also need $y \le x - \delta$. As you can check that $a+\delta \le x \le b+\delta$, you have $x - \delta \le b$, so the true bounds on $y$ are $a \le y \le \min(b, x-\delta)$, i.e., $a \le y \le x-\delta$. So

$$\begin{align}f_2(x) 
&= \int_{a}^{x-\delta} f_{2,y}(x)f_1(y) dy \\
&= \int_{a}^{x-\delta} \frac{1}{b-y} \frac{1}{b-a} dy \\
&= \frac{1}{b-a} \ln\frac{b-a}{b-(x-\delta)}
\end{align}$$
for $x \in (a+\delta, b+\delta)$, and $0$ outside.

The fact that this $f_2(x)$ varies with $x$ shows that $X_2$ is not uniformly distributed. However, when you integrate over the entire region $(a+\delta, b+\delta)$, you get $1$ as you should, so it *is* a valid distribution: $P(X_2 \in (a+\delta, b+\delta))$ is

$$\begin{align} \int_{a+\delta}^{b+\delta} f_2(x) dx
&= \int_{a+\delta}^{b+\delta} \frac{1}{b-a} \ln\frac{b-a}{b-(x-\delta)} dx \\
&= \int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{b-a} \ln\frac{b-a}{b-u} du \quad \text{ substituting } u=x-\delta\\
&= \ln(b-a) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{a}^{b}\ln(b-u) \  du \\
&= \ln(b-a) - \frac{1}{b-a} \int_{0}^{b-a} \ln t \ dt \quad \text{ substituting } t=b-u \\
&= \ln(b-a) - \frac{1}{b-a} ((b-a)\ln(b-a) - (b-a)) \\
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking now about the discrete case. $P(X_1=x_1)=\frac{1}{b-a}$, so $P(X_2=x_2) = \sum_{x_1\in X_1} \frac{1}{b-a+1}\cdot \frac{1}{b+\delta-(x_1+\delta)+1}=\frac{1}{b-a+1} \sum_{x_1=a}^b \frac{1}{b-x_1+1}$.

Comment: @Antonin: Do you mean for the discrete case? Because for the continuous case (the one in the question), you should get an answer of $E[X_2] = \delta + 3b/4+a/4$, rather than such a complicated expression. This is because $X_2 \sim U(X_1+\delta, b+\delta) = \delta + U(X_1,b)$, so $$E[X_2|X_1] = \delta + (X_1 + b)/2 = \delta + b/2 + X_1/2$$ and so $$E[X_2] = E[E[X_2|X_1]] = \delta + b/2 + E[X_1]/2 = \delta + b/2 + ((a+b)/2)/2 = \delta + 3b/4 + a/4.$$ In fact your expression simplifies to the same thing, if you replace the $2a\delta$ with $-2a\delta$ (which is probably what it should be).